# How to save description from TEXT_DETECTION response

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

How to save the `description:` portion of the response? 
I tried

```
response = client.text_detection(image=image)
plateNumber = response.description
```

assuming that it is a JSON object, but it gives an error saying

`AttributeError: 'AnnotateImageResponse' object has no attribute 'description'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over each of the individual text annotations instead:

```
response = client.text_detection(image=image)
texts = response.text_annotations

for text in texts:
    print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description))
```

Comment: Is it possible to access them via index?

Comment: Sure, something like `response.text_annotations[n].description` should work.